# Building app with neo4j as library in Android

Tags: java, android, neo4j

I am trying to write an Android App which will use **neo4j embedded** APIs for graph database. For developing the app I am using Android Studio [preview version](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html) which supports Java 8. The building is happening properly. However when I am trying to run the application on a target, I am getting the following errors in gradle console:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: InvokeDynamic not supported
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: InvokeDynamic not supported
Error:  at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:183)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilder.processOutputs(DexArchiveBuilder.java:95)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilder.convert(DexArchiveBuilder.java:78)
Error:  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.lambda$cacheMissAction$0(DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.java:240)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.lambda$createFile$1(FileCache.java:260)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.lambda$null$5(FileCache.java:443)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.doActionWithMultiProcessLocking(SynchronizedFile.java:265)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.write(SynchronizedFile.java:232)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.lambda$queryCacheEntry$6(FileCache.java:415)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.doActionWithMultiProcessLocking(SynchronizedFile.java:265)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.read(SynchronizedFile.java:215)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.queryCacheEntry(FileCache.java:391)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.createFile(FileCache.java:273)
Error:  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.getFromCacheAndCreateIfMissing(DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.java:187)
Error:  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.call(DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.java:149)
Error:  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.call(DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.java:53)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
Error:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Error:Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: InvokeDynamic not supported
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.determineOffsets(ConstantPoolParser.java:226)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:132)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:491)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderCallable.parseClass(DexArchiveBuilderCallable.java:80)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderCallable.call(DexArchiveBuilderCallable.java:66)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderCallable.call(DexArchiveBuilderCallable.java:40)
Error:  ... 6 more
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.utils.FileCache$FileCreatorException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilder$DexBuilderException: Unable to convert input to dex archive.
```

I searched in the Internet and came to know that the `InvokeDynamic not supported` error mainly occurs when my application is trying to use a third party library which has dependencies on lambda. However since I am using the preview edition of Android studio, which supports Java 8, shouldn't lambda have worked ?

Has anyone faced this issue with Neo4j? Any idea on how to address the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Android Studio support for Java 8 features in libraries is not full.

I've experimented with Android Studio 2.4 Preview 7, compilation for my project fails with the same error when I link a library containing this simple class using a *method reference* feature:

```
public class LambdaTest {

    public void test() {
        Runnable runnable = this::run;
        runnable.run();
    }

    public void run() {
    }

}
```

A workaround is to put the sources for your library directly into main Android module (if those sources are available and license allows that). Or, wait for Android Studio updates that should address this issue.

Comment: Did you try building with Jack toolchain?

Comment: Jack has no (and will never have) support for Java 8 libraries, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37101513

Comment: It seems that is the case. I was able to generate the APK using Jack, but neo4j had some dependency on Java libraries, viz. MangementFactory,  which will run only on JVM.